# ALAssetGroup poster image size

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

Can someone explain what is the size of `posterImage` of `AlassetGroup`?

I do not understand what is the dependency on image and poster image of the album. For example as I tested poster image size on iPad usually is 80x80, but some images have 90x90 or even 110x110? How is it calculated?

I need to know what smallest poster image size can i get on different iOS devices and iOS versions?